# firebase_admin in kivy and buildozer

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, firebase-admin, buildozer

I'm using firebase_admin with python 3.8
On my computer it works very well but when I package the application with buildozer it breaks, does not run after installed on Android.

1 - Is there a mdelo application that shows the use with kivy?
2 - Is the spec file missing something?

Comment: Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64051149/kivymd-buildozer-android-and-firebase-admin).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is missing all you need is to add the following modules in your
buildozer.spec

```
requests, openssl, urllib3, chardet, idna, jwt, cryptography, pyparsing, firebase_admin, PIL, google-auth, cachetools, pyasn1, pyasn1_modules, rsa, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-firestore, google-api-core,  protobuf, cachecontrol, gcloud, google-cloud, httplib2
```

and in permission allow internet accesses like this

```
android.permissions = INTERNET
```

and you can write in your terminal for viewing logs while your app is running on your phone

```
buildozer android debug deploy run logcat
```

but you will need to allow to see only python logs by doing this in your buildozer.spec

```
[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2
```

if you didn't understand there is a Youtuber named Erick Sandberg you should watch his video about deploying an android app